# org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone stores timezone with hours

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, timezone-offset

in my project we switched to hibernate 4 and jadira usertypes 3.2.0.GA.

When a result is stored in DB (in my case Oracle) the timezone is stored like this: 'Europe/Zurick{+02:00}' and before update just: 'Europe/Zurich'.

The question is: does the hours informaiton {+02:00} need to be stored? if not is there an option to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are storing the zone as a String because you didn't mention the type you are using. You need to store the hours. Otherwise there is a possible ambiguity during DST cutover when the clocks roll backwards.

For backwards compatibility, the code will interpret zone columns that don't provide the hours information.

Disclaimer: I maintain Jadira Usertype.